# ListView doesn't show adapter

Tags: android, simpleadapter, illegalstateexception

With this piece of code

```
            final ListView lw   =   (ListView) findViewById( R.id.book_list );
        lw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        ListView listBookView   =   (ListView) findViewById( R.id.book_list );
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> my_list  = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

        for ( int x=0; x< book_list.size(); x++)
        {
            String[] valori_book    =   book_list.get( x ).getObjVars();
            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("book", valori_book[ 0 ]);
            map.put("descr", valori_book[ 1 ] );

            my_list.add(map);
        }
        // ...
        SimpleAdapter showMenu = new SimpleAdapter(this, my_list, R.layout.activity_book_booklistmask,
                    new String[] { "book" , "descr" }, new int[] {R.id.nome_quaderno, R.id.descrizione_quaderno});
        listBookView.setAdapter(showMenu);
```

java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.widget.ListView is not a  view that can be bounds by this SimpleAdapter

The logcat doesn't write the error's row of my project so i don't know where check :/

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  904): java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.widget.ListView is not a  view that can be bounds by this SimpleAdapter
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.bindView(SimpleAdapter.java:195)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:126)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:909)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(  904):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Copy and paste your log cat, Thnks

Comment: Here it is the complete log cat:

Comment: Try using ArrayAdapter seems like you are using content in SimpleAdapter which throws illegalstateexception, Try changing the way you put your data in your list!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the SimpleAdapter documentation

A view that implements Checkable (e.g. CheckBox). The expected bind value is a boolean.

TextView. The expected bind value is a string and setViewText(TextView, String) is invoked.

ImageView. The expected bind value is a resource id or a string and setViewImage(ImageView, int) or setViewImage(ImageView, String) is invoked.

It would appear that passing an Object as the mapped object is not compatible with SimpleAdapter. Change the object type, or create a custom adapter (I recommend the later)

Comment: I don't understand you advise, I'm sorry.
Where I should change the object type?

Comment: Your hashmap is HashMap<String, Object>, You need to either change the Object to be a type the SimpleAdapter can work with, or build your own adapter

Comment: Where can I found an easy how to relize a custom adapter?